# 50% of Ram used when Idle, Games run with massive performance issues

Tags: memory, performance, windows-11, memory-leaks

Recently, my computer started to use almost 50% of ram while idle. Not only this, but all of a sudden while multi-tasking programs slowed down, I had been able to run these programs simultaneously without any issue before. Many games that I had been able to run easily, now have much performance problems.

I do not understand why this has happened, I have attached screenshots of Task Manager, RamMap and poolmon. any help would be appreciated in finding and fixing the problem.

[poolmon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhhra.png)
[RAMmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksCd1.png)
[Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiayX.png)

I have reinstalled intel storage drivers, as I saw the massive amount of ram 'ismc' was using, however that has not fixed the problem.

Comment: Showing that view of task manager is borderline worthless.  The details tab sorted by memory might actually be helpful.  Also, this is probably not a "memory-leak" as your tag implies.  Memory leaks occur when a c/c++ application allocate memory without freeing said memory.  Why I point out c/c++ is because they manage their own memory where "garbage collected" languages do this automatically (with a performance cost).  That is probably not what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Bhaskar,
It appears you may have some malware running in the background.  You probably have already run some scans.  This may be crypto mining or a botnet running in background.  Before re-installing your operating system it might be good to run a Malwarebytes scan.   It can be downloaded as a "trial" and used then delete it if you choose not to keep it.